# Creating Nextjs 13 App returns "5 moderate severity vulnerabilities"

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

when creating a new Nextjs 13 app using `npm create-next-app@lastest` with the default configuration, I get:

```
'added 343 packages, and audited 344 packages in 27s

127 packages are looking for funding
  run "npm fund" for details

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run "npm audit" for details.
Success! Created test-3 at {project directory}
```

and when I run `npm audit`, I get:

```
# npm audit report

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install eslint-config-next@12.0.4, which is a breaking change
node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/node_modules/semver
node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/node_modules/semver
node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/node_modules/semver
  eslint-plugin-import  >=2.27.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
  eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y  >=6.6.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
  eslint-plugin-react  7.19.0 || >=7.26.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-react
    eslint-config-next  >=12.0.5-canary.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of eslint-plugin-react
    node_modules/eslint-config-next

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

so I run `npm audit fix` and get the same result as when I run `npm audit` (the section above). I instead run `npm audit fix --force`

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating eslint-config-next to 12.0.4, which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm WARN Found: eslint@8.44.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@4.33.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-next/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.20.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm WARN   eslint-config-next@"12.0.4" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm WARN     eslint-config-next@"12.0.4" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm WARN Found: peer eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7" from the root project

added 5 packages, removed 44 packages, changed 10 packages, and audited 305 packages in 5s

100 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/semver
  eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y  >=6.6.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
  eslint-plugin-react  7.19.0 || >=7.26.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-react

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

And I cannot fix the remaining 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities. Any solutions?

**EDIT - SOLVED**
the solution is when using `npm create-next-app@lastest` select NO to the use ESLINT prompt.

Comment: ESlint matters in other cases (that's why it was added in `create-next-app` in the first place), you could easily ignore 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities. And since you don't want to use EsLint, it's up to you. Also, please add answers in the below answer box - don't edit your question to include the answer!